# Whats use of following code in lovefactory extension joomla?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions, joomla3.0

```php
$newMembership = JTable::getInstance('MembershipSold', 'Table');
$newMembership->load($this->membership_sold_id);
$this->membership_sold = $newMembership;
$dispatcher->trigger('onAfterMembershipChanged', array($newMembership));
return parent::store();/* whats the use of above code */
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `$newMembership = JTable::getInstance('MembershipSold', 'Table');`
   This line is getting is a static method to get an instance of a JTable class, specifically one called "MembershipSold". You can read about [JTable](http://docs.joomla.org/Using_the_JTable_class) (Joomla's abstract table class) here, the document is a little out of date but you can read the relevant JTable class in your Joomla installation at `/libraries/joomla/database/table.php`
2. `$newMembership->load($this->membership_sold_id);`
   This line uses the `membership_sold_id` to load a record from the table in the database.
3. `$this->membership_sold = $newMembership;`
   This line inserts the JTable object (now holding the record loaded from the table) into the `$this`.
4. `$dispatcher->trigger('onAfterMembershipChanged', array($newMembership));`
   This line appears to be triggering an event and passing in the `$newMembership` object (Joomla supports a basic event system for plugins etc to act on), you can read more about it in this document "[Supporting plugins in your component](http://docs.joomla.org/Supporting_plugins_in_your_component)"
5. `return parent::store();`
   This line is calling the current objects `parent`'s `store()` method. See [PHP:parent](http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.parent.php)